# R shiny application not displaying in default window unless R Studio is restarted

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

When I go to run any R shiny application the first time it displays properly in the default R studio window. However if I go to run the code again I get a blank screen as shown below and I have to click "Open in Browser" to have it displayed properly. This happens no matter the complexity of the code even with something simple like the code below. The only way of fixing this is if I restart my R Studio entirely.

```
RStudio 2022.12.0+353 "Elsbeth Geranium" Release 
(7d165dcfc1b6d300eb247738db2c7076234f6ef0, 2022-12-03) for Windows

version
               _                                
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32               
arch           x86_64                           
os             mingw32                          
crt            ucrt                             
system         x86_64, mingw32                  
status                                          
major          4                                
minor          2.2                              
year           2022                             
month          10                               
day            31                               
svn rev        83211                            
language       R                                
version.string R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
nickname       Innocent and Trusting
```

```
library("shiny")
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput(inputId="test", label="Test", choices=1:4, inline = TRUE)
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you raise this as an issue with the RStudio/Posit folks or the shiny devs on github?

Comment: @michael no I did not as it works for my coworkers and my personal pc and figured it was something really weirdly specific I was doing.... but that would be a good idea. But also the comment below maybe means we just try and re-download R.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was having the same problem using Rstudio version 2022.12.0. I updated all packages and also tried reverting back to R version 4.2.1 (I was using 4.2.2) but the problem remained.

I eventually fixed it by going back to RStudio 2022.07.02 (downloaded [here](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/older-versions/)) and it is currently working as normal with R 4.2.2. In conclusion, it looks like a bug in the latest (at time of writing) version of Rstudio.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server,options=c(launch.browser = .rs.invokeShinyPaneViewer))
```

to force shiny to always render in the viewer pane.

Comment: thanks, that worked. Id like for it to still work per usual but this is better than having to open it in a browser tab every time